# How to pull 2 level domains from list of 3 level and 2 level domains in hive SQL?

Tags: sql, hive

I am having a list of mix level domains for example:

```
www.google.com
xyz.com
www.facebook.com
abc.com
```

I want to fetch the below domains:

```
xyz.com
abc.com
```

Something like rlike in hive

Kindly let me know the best way to extract the domains.

Comment: Do you have any SQL or queries to show what you have tried already? What research have you already looked at to try to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use `like`:

```
select domain
from t
where domain like '%.%' and domain not like '%.%.%'
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6e3972ec1556f02dd7f91f1c04d610e2) is a db<>fiddle.  It uses Postgres, but this is standard SQL and should work the same in any database.

Comment: It didn't work for me. It's still pulling all the domains

Comment: @jay . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  This code should work, on any database (the code is not database dependent).

Comment: I gave an example of 3 levels but in reality, I have data such as:
abc.xyz.google.com
4477.abc.xyz.com
abcde.com

The solution provided by you is static

I am looking for a solution like  rlike '[^a-z][^0-9].[^a-z][^0-9].$' . It's not working but looking for this kind of match

Comment: @jay . . . This answers the question you have asked.  I would suggest that if you have a different question, you should ask it as a *new* question; this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the above question is:

select domain from dual where domain rlike '^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*.?[a-zA-Z]{2,}.$'